# Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the error

> Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain
>   JavaScript object.

when updating a document, using firebase admin SDK. Here the Typescript code.

```
var myDoc = new MyDoc();
myDoc.Public.Name = "Jonh Doe" //setup up content

admin.firestore()
     .collection('MyDocs')
     .doc("Id1")
     .set(myDoc);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case someone else bump into the same issue, the solution is to simply use JSON to instantiate the object, like this:

```
var myDoc = {
        Public: {
            Name: "Jonh Doe"
        }
    } as MyDoc; //keep type to still get typescript compiler validations
```

Answer (score 5):

I did something similar:

```
var myDoc = <MyDoc> {
    Public: {
        Name: "Jonh Doe"
    }
}
```

It is semantically the same, I just think it is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, in my case I'd forgot to add `Content-Type:application/json` to my header when sending request, and then the object was treated as string and I got that error.

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate js object via; `{...__data}`

```
return refDB.set({...__data}).then((newData) => {

})
```

Comment: Can you more specific? What you get?. This is modern approach, maybe your nodejs version is not enough.

Comment: To be fair, I was using js instead of ts, which might have been it. However, I ended up using update() instead like this `this.firestore.collection('influencers').doc(influencerDoc.id).update(data)`

Comment: main issue for this error, newly created object has some prototype which is hidden element of array will verifiying from firebase library or api. If you created new object and pass data, problem partialy solved. But i didn't go deeper. So i don't have exact answer.